# Garbage Collector not working or memory leak with http client c#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, dotnet-httpclient

I am calling an OAuth endpoint using `HttpClient` in C# inside a Windows service. I am passing the username and password along with grant type as `FormUrlEncodedContent` inside `PostAsync`.

But whenever I am taking the memory dump of the Windows service, it is showing the credential information there (username, password, grant type).

As showing sensitive information in memory dump is not good, I have tried forcing the GC to collect the memory after the call is done but of no use.

This is the code I am using: after many approaches I found that issue is with `FormUrlEncodedContent` as in memory dump I am seeing the information as urlencoded.

```
var requestBody = new Dictionary<string, string>
                  {
                      { "grant_type", "password" },
                      { "username", "someuser" },
                      { "password", "somepassword") },
                  };

HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(BaseServiceAddress + "/oauth2/token"), new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestBody));
```

[image: memory dump]

Edit: I have even tried with using `JsonContent` instead of `FormUrlEncodedContent` but same issue, it shows as json in memory dump instead of url encoded.

Comment: How did you create your `httpclient` & release your `httpclient`

Comment: I tried both approaches by creating it locally and putting it inside 'using' and also globally as recommended by Microsoft to re-use the same httpclient. I have even tried to dispose it in finally block.

Comment: Try disposing that `HttpResponseMessage`, e.g.  `using HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = ...`

Comment: Already tried not working

Comment: *"As showing sensitive information in memory dump is not good, I have tried forcing the GC to collect the memory after the call is done but of no use."* - but why? Are you sending those dumps somewhere? And what do you understand by "no use" in *"I have tried forcing the GC to collect the memory after the call is done but of no use"*? GC is generational, many data may stay in memory even after GC.

Comment: @KonradKokosa i am not sending the dumps to anywhere. As it's a windows service which is part of some desktop application so a user can take the dump of the windows service and can see the sensitive information about the APIs which this desktop application calls to get the token, so it's a security issue. I have tried to collect all the generations of GC but still that info is there in the memory dump.

Comment: Do users enter the password or its just hardcoded in the app?

Comment: @HMZ it's not hard-coded, it is encrypted in the app config and just before calling the api it is decrypted inside the method which calls the api.

Comment: I think HttpClient is one of the flaws of.net